# how to make a 'window.location' based on the two selects

Tags: jquery

I have two selects. I want to let jquery know for example if white is selected in one of them and green is selected in the other one when the button is clicked, so it can do something  (e.g. go to http://stackoverflow.com).

```
<select id="filter-select">
   <option value="white">white</option>
   <option value="black">black</option>
</select>

<select id="filter-select">
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: use conditional statements like if or case statements

Comment: Please post the code you've tried already so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PS: You will not be able to redirect here because of the restriction of stackoverflow.

```js
function redirectPage () {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('filter-select')[0].value == "white" || document.getElementsByClassName('filter-select')[1].value == "green") {
    window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";  
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="filter-select">
  <option value="white">white</option>
  <option value="black">black</option>
</select>

<select class="filter-select">
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="redirectPage()">Click Me!</button>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/